# 14.04 Graphics/Windowing Problem - icons and window text disappear!

Tags: 14.04, graphics

I loaded Ubuntu 14.04 to what used to be a Windows Media Center PC computer. The install went without a hitch. However, after completing all the updating to get the system current. I have encountered problems.
The machine is as follows (per System Settings-Details)
Memory: 495.3 MiB
Processor: Intel® Pentium(R) 4 CPU 2.53GHz
Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits)
OS Type: 32-bit (I chose '32 bit' due to small RAM configuration)
Disk: 117.5 GB

In applications with lists of things in windows (eg. System Monitor-Processes, Ubuntu Software Center-Installed Applications), the lists (both icons and text) disappear if the mouse moves over the icon/text area in the window area. Scrolling the screen using the mouse brings the text and icons back, until the mouse moves over the window area again.

In the System Settings window only some of my icons appear. When I hover my mouse over the 'missing' icon in most cases it shows up, but as my mouse moves away the icon disappears, again.

I have already tried 'Gnome Fallback' but that did not help either problem. Things seem to work OK within a browser so I'm thinking it might a graphics card or driver issue???? I'm a Ubuntu neophyte so please don't bury me in 'geek' talk.

Any suggestions of things to try would be appreciated....... Thanks........ Phil

Comment: I reverted to 12.04.5.  There is still some 'fading' of window data going on, but I am not experiencing the complete disappearance of data and icons as in 14.04.  Mouse movements over the data windows seem to have something to do with the disappearance and reappearance of the information.  I'll keep an eye on this question and if a good answer is proposed I can reload 14.04 and try it out.  Thanks..........  Phil

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem with disappearing text, especially in synaptic. In my case the problem disappeared (and the text reappeared) after switching "Subpixel-Geometry" to be found in the font menu of Appearance from whatever it was before to "none". Unfortunately, I dont know any explanation for that, because I just found it by trial-and-error.